# Merging rows of a dataframe into single one using python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-cleaning

I am doing some stuff using pandas in python and came across one dataset that needs to be clean.
It looks likes this-
[image]

I need to merge rows of index 0,1,2,3 into 1 single row by avoiding NaN value. Also, after doing this, I want to remove the default header and make the newly made row the default name for columns.
I tried to use groupby operation in pandas but nothing is happening.
Any idea on this?

Thanks
Akhi

Comment: if you more than one values in rows on same column what will you do?? eg Unamed0 ,  0 Table, 1 Name which data is you need

Comment: Just add them in string form

Comment: You are asking that to concat string with comma

Comment: I'll concatenate with space.

Answer (score 0):

pd.DataFrame([df.aggregate(lambda x:" ".join(str(e).strip() for e in x if not pd.isna(e))).tolist()],columns=[<add_new_list here>])